# How to keep script from swallowing all of stdin?

Tags: ssh, shell, expect, stdin

I have a script that reads from a pipe in a loop and runs an expect script and a normal shell script in the loop. Both scripts run ssh to another server to grab a piece of data.  For example:

```
cat /tmp/file |
while read a b c d
do
   s=`expect-script server1 $b`
   c=`ssh $b normal-script`
   echo $s $c
done
```

Even though there are many lines in /tmp/file, the script quits after processing the first line. I suspect that the expect script is swallowing all of stdin so that when it returns, there is nothing left to read. How can I avoid this? I don't want any of the scripts I call to read from the stdin of the main script.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["while read line" returns early when calling ssh "mysql..."](http://serverfault.com/questions/513858/while-read-line-returns-early-when-calling-ssh-mysql)

Comment: The possible duplicate is similar, but not identical. I can't use the -n option of ssh, because the ssh is called by the Expect script, which requires reading from stdin. I will play around with the redirection solution to see if that works for me.

Comment: Ah I see. Check the solution of this problem in different in another stackexchange network http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107800/using-while-loop-to-ssh-to-multiple-servers

Comment: Yes, that solution helped me get it to work, especially Richard Hansen's comment. Thank you!

Comment: @masegaloeh, I suggest adding an answer with that link, which Justin can accept, so that this question doesn't remain marked as unanswered.

Answer (score 4):

It's actually `ssh` that's slurping up stdin. Just add the `-n` option:

```
    c=$( ssh -n $b normal-script )
```

If you don't want to do that, you can have your shell `while` loop read from a different file descriptor, leaving stdin untouched:

```
while read -u3 a b c d
do
    s=$( expect-script server1 $b )
    c=$( ssh $b normal-script )
    echo $s $c
done 3< /tmp/file
```

(assuming bash/ksh/zsh for the `read -u` option)

Answer (score 3):

```
cat /tmp/file |
while read a b c d
do
    {
        s=`expect-script server1 $b`
        c=`ssh $b normal-script`
        echo $s $c
    } < /dev/null
done
```

The `{ command... }` syntax allows you to apply redirection or piping to a sequence of commands.

I'll also note that you don't need `cat` in your example. You could do this:

```
while read a b c d
do
    ...
done < /tmp/file
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, generally speaking, if you don't want some command to use **current** STDIN, you provide it with different one using `<`.

E.g.

```
   s=`expect-script server1 $b < /dev/null`
```

would make "expect-script" read it's STDIN from `/dev/null` (which happens to just return `EOF`) instead of consuming your current one (from `/tmp/file`)

You can also use `|` to provide some separate STDIN just for that command, e.g.

```
   s=`cat /tmp/stdin_for_expect | expect-script server1 $b`
   c=`cat /tmp/stdin_for_ssh | ssh $b normal-script`
```